# Question about interest rates

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

Can someone help me with this

Anna borrows $50, 000$ to the bank at a nominal interest rate $i(12) = 6\%$, (compounded monthly). She repays this loan by doing monthly payments (at the end of each month) during $6$ years. If each of the $36$  rst payments are of $R$ and each one of the last $36$ payments are of $(R + 1000)$.
Using geometric series, determine $R$, and the interest amount that Anna paid to the bank.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I found that at after the 72 months, Anna will have paid 71 602,2139$ and I am stuck here ..

Answer (score 0):

$50,000 = R \sum_\limits {n=1}^{36} \frac {1}{1.005^n} + (R+1000) \sum_\limits {n=37}^{72} \frac {1}{1.005^n}\\
50,000= R \frac {1.005^{36} - 1}{(0.005) (1.005^{36})} + \frac {(R+1000)}{1.005^{36}}\frac {1.005^{36} - 1}{(0.005) (1.005^{36})} $

$50,000 \frac {(0.005)(1.005^{72})}{1.005^{36} - 1}= R (1.005^{36} + 1) + 1000\\
R =50,000 \frac {(0.005)(1.005^{72})}{1.005^{72} - 1} - \frac {1000}{1.005^{36} + 1}$

Total payments $= 72 R + 36,000$

Total Interest = Total payments - 50,000

Comment: Where is the 1.01 coming from ??

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: sorry, 1.005... I had 12% interest in my mind as I was typing

Comment: In the first equation, I thought that 71 602,2139 should be equal to the summation of the payment ?

Comment: I get 373.41 for the first 36 payments, 1,373.41 for the next 36, Total payments 62,886.

Comment: I just don't understand why 50 000 equal the two summation ..?

Comment: thank you for you explications

Comment: The amount borrowed equals the NPV of the future payments.

Comment: Oh Ok I got it ! But when I do 50 000(1+0.06/12)^72 it gives me 71 602,2139, it is not suppose to be the same as the total payment that you calculated ?

Comment: I agree $50,000(1.005)^{72} = 71,602$ but that is only part of the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that the cash flow can be regarded as an annuity-immediate of $R$ per month for $72$ months, plus a second annuity-immediate of $1000$ per month for the last $36$ months of payment.  That is to say, the present value of the cash flow can be written as $$50000 = R a_{\overline{72}\rceil j} + 1000 v^{36} a_{\overline{36}\rceil j},$$ where $j = i^{(12)}/12 = 0.06/12 = 0.005$ is the effective monthly interest rate, and $v = 1/(1+j) \approx 0.995025$ is the effective monthly discount factor.  Since $$a_{\overline{n}\rceil j} = \frac{1 - v^n}{j} = \frac{1 - (1+j)^{-n}}{j},$$ the computation is straightforward:  $$R = 1000 \left( \frac{50 - v^{36} a_{\overline{36}\rceil j}}{a_{\overline{72}\rceil j}} \right) = 1000 \left( \frac{50 - (0.835645)(32.871)}{60.3395} \right) \approx 373.412.$$  The total amount paid is simply $72R + 36000$, and the total interest paid is $72R + 36000 - 50000$.

It is worth noting that one can write $$\frac{50 - v^{36} a_{\overline{36}\rceil j}}{a_{\overline{72}\rceil j}} = \frac{50j - (v^{36} - v^{72})}{1 - v^{72}} = \frac{0.25 - y + y^2}{1 - y^2},$$ where $y = v^{36} = 0.835645$, which simplifies the computation slightly since now the value of $R$ is expressible in terms of the single value $y$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but what the heck,

The residual debt after first 36 payments is:
$L(1+i)^{36}-R\frac{(1+i)^{36}-1}{i}$

After the last 36 payments the residual debt is zero:

$L(1+i)^{72}-R\frac{(1+i)^{36}-1}{i}(1+i)^{36}-(R+1000)\frac{(1+i)^{36}-1}{i}=0$

$R=Li\frac{(1+i)^{72}}{(1+i)^{72}-1}-\frac{1000}{(1+i)^{36}+1}, L=50000, i=0.005$

R=373.42